# Kentico - Disable Page Level Attachments

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

Is there a way to disable page attachments in Kentico without using the UI Personalization? because our current site doesn't have the UI Personalization enabled but still want to disable page level attachments.

[image]